# Creating index in ravendb with Nodatime's LocalDate

Tags: c#, ravendb, ravendb-studio

I hope somebody can help me.
I'm using Ravendb with the Nodatime bundles, and so far I didn't have any problem with it until I wanted to use some nodatime methods during index creation.

Product:

```
public class Product {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public LocalDate ReleasedDate { get; set; }
    // and more properties...
}
```

My index creation (AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask):

```
AddMap<Product>(Product =>
            from product in products
            let dateTimeUTc = DateTimeZone.Utc.AtStartOfDay(product.ReleasedDate)
            let timeTicks = dateTimeUTc.ToInstant().Ticks
            let hash = $"{product.Id}|{timeTicks}"

            select new IndexEntry
            {
                Hash = hash,
                Usage = 0
            });
```

With that the index is being generated, the ticks are there, nothing is wrong except that I get an indexing error for each index record in ravendb:

`The best overloaded method match for 'NodaTime.DateTimeZone.AtStartOfDay(NodaTime.LocalDate)' has some invalid arguments`

Does anybody know why is that?